# opening a selected file or directory

Tags: c#

I will try to explain this clearly.  Using the mouse, we select files or directories in explorer, and what I want to know is, when an item gets selected (may be a file or a dir), I want to open the selected item programmatically.

It's a bit difficult for me.  I want to know how to get the window handle of a selected
 or focused file or dir.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean in explorer, or in a tree view in your application?

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of opening a new one.

Comment: @Schenck, Vinoth was probably discouraged when his question was closed.  A close question isn't look at as much as an open one.  The closed one will be gone soon enough, anyway, and reopenning is difficult.  I think it's fine that he opened another question.

Comment: Sorry didn't know it was closed.

Comment: Vinoth: I mean no offence, but I strongly suspect you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Can you tell us - with lots of detail - what you are trying to do, from start to end. As it stands, your question does not make sense, this is why you are getting bad answers.

Comment: There is no "window handle" for a selected/focused file in Windows Explorer. There seems to be some basic misunderstanding. Could you please explain your original problem? Seems the way you want to solve it might not be a good one.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) ?

Comment: may be your son will give a better answer

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer given the question is very vague. If you want help you should be more specific (and at least be polite).

Comment: don't have a son, so I doubt that.